# python convert au to km

Tags: python, skyfield

I'm trying to write a very simple programm, that prints the current distance to any planet in kilometers. I'm using Skyfield.
Here's my code for Mars:

```
from skyfield.api import earth, mars, now
ra, dec, distance = earth(now()).observe(mars).radec()


print(distance)
```

This will print out the distance in astronomical units.
In order to convert to kilometers, i tried to multiply by 149597871:

```
from skyfield.api import earth, mars, now
ra, dec, distance = earth(now()).observe(mars).radec()


print(distance*149597871)
```

But this returns an Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Distance' and 'int'
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`distance` is a `Distance` object, so you can simply use `distance.km` if you want the distance in km. If you want to do the conversion yourself, you can use `distance.AU * 149597871`. (If it doesn't match exactly, it's because Skyfield uses 149597870.700 km/au for conversion).

You can see the implementation of this class in the source [here](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/python-skyfield/blob/master/skyfield/units.py).

Comment: I'd change "you have to use" to "you can simply use".

Comment: Thanks @RussellBorogove, that's better wording and I expanded on it a bit.